# While Importing Selenium2Library in Robot Framework comes in RED color

Tags: python, windows, selenium2library, robotframework-ide

I installed Selenium2Library thorough `pip install robotframework-selenium2library`.

There were no errors during the installation process

> Folder placed in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library

And I also run this following command from a command line succeeds without errors:

python

```
import Selenium2Library

x = Selenium2Library.Selenium2Library()

x.open_browser("https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/issues/565")
```

Comment: it's a `pylint` issue, not able to detect installed library. Try to restart your editor.

Comment: Why the old Selenium2Library and not the new SeleniumLibrary?. On RIDE when you have RED color import, there is entry on Tools»RIDE Log it may help to understand why.